# Different shiny embed in rmarkdown behavior depending on web browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server

I've created a shiny app that is embed in rmarkdown and is distributed via local shiny-server. The application presents dygraphs that can be set to display values only for specific dates. The problem is that when I try to set dates under Mozilla Firefox and under Google Chrome it appears that I can not select the same dates under those 2 browsers. Under Firefox I can select 18-10-2015 but under Google Chrome I can not. The bug is presented on the image below. Did anyone know what can be the causeof such behavior and how to overcome this inconvinience?

[image]